# Нужно ли тире?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать: *ИТ-технологии, ИТ-консалтинг, ИТ-бюджет* и т.д. Или: ​*ИТ технологии, ИТ консалтинг, ИТ бюджет*?

Answer (score 1):

Я не встречал специальных рекомендаций конкретно по поводу ИТ, на практике применяют и дефисное, и раздельное написание. И оба варианта не лишены смысла. Но я бы предпочёл дефис. Тут второе слово вроде как приложение получается.