# ИТ–индустрия или индустрия ИТ?

Tags: орфография, раздельно-дефис, сложные-слова, аббревиатура

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно писать?

1. ИТ–индустрия.
2. Индустрия ИТ.

Мое понимание следующее. Все (включая меня) привыкли писать «ИТ–индустрия», но где–то внутри я понимаю, что причина тому «IT–индустрия», что есть полуперевод «IT industry». В английском языке мы используем описательные существительные перед существительным, которое описываем. В русском языке мы так не делаем, мы используем окончания. То есть, если раскрыть фразу, получается «Информационных Технологий Индустрия». Выглядит, как минимум, загадочно.
Верно ли, что на русском языке правильно писать «индустрия ИТ», то есть «Индустрия Информационных Технологий»? Или все–таки никакой разницы нет?

Дополнение: есть ли какое–то общее правило правописания в подобных случаях?

Comment: Я думаю, в английском срабатывает _конверсия_: если подряд стоят два существительных, первое из них конвертируется в прилагательное. В русском языке такого правила, насколько мне известно, нет. Но при написании через дефис, возможно, действуют другие правила.

Comment: Я, кстати, не уверен, что само сокращение ИТ в русском языке устоялось.

Comment: Подобный вопрос был задан более пяти лет назад: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/Нужно-ли-тире. Значит, устоялось. Возможно, эти два вопроса стоит объединить?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Спасибо за ссылку! Мне кажется, там вопрос больше про написание с дефисом или без. Меня интересует место, где должна писаться аббревиатура.

Comment: @VladD Да–да! Я именно о том, что в английском такая последовательность слов логична, в связи с наличием формы с описательными существительными, которых в русском языке нет. Фразу ИТ–индустрия и, что хуже, IT–индустрия (IT–специалист, IT–отдел) встречаю каждый день!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сегодня написание ИТ-индустрия уже можно считать устоявшимся.  К тому же, надо помнить, оно было заимствовано в таком виде как термин.

В спровочнике по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация, Розенталь, Д.Э. правило звучит так:

> Научно-технические термины, в состав которых входят названия букв или буквы (чаще всего греческого или латинского алфавита): альфа-частица, икс-лучи (х-лучи), к-частица, пи-мезон;Обычно в русском языке термины, состоящие из буквенных обозначений

Примерно так же это правило сформулировано и Полном академическом справочнике под редакцией Лопатина.

Ср.:Т-образный, IBM-совместимый, γ-активный, «S-образное движение ловкого тела» (Купр.), ww-образные трубки,ИК-приемник, укв -передатчик.

Как видно из примеров, буквенное обозначение всегда препозитивно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Из примеров следует, что писать можно вообще как угодно, включая IT–индустрия, верно?

Comment: Как раз-таки нет. Из примеров следует, что первая часть сложных слов, в состав которых входят буквы, пишутся через дефис. Причем буквы стоят впереди.

Comment: Подскажите, какой при этом используется язык? То есть «IT» или все–таки «ИТ»?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, судя по примерам `икс-лучи (х-лучи)` - без разницы